# minimum number of platforms required on that railway station

Tags: java

Given arrival and departure times of all trains for a particular railway station, write code to find the minimum number of platforms required on that railway station, so that all trains can run according to their schedule.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: ["3. Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Current state of your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Use [edit] option to improve it. Also read this [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.extra;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MinimumPlatformRequired {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MinimumPlatformRequired  m=new MinimumPlatformRequired();
         Double arr[]  = {9.0,  9.40, 9.50,  11.00, 15.00, 18.00};
         Double dep[]  = {9.10, 12.00, 11.20, 11.30, 19.00, 20.00};
         System.out.println("maximum Platform  Required:"+m.getMinimumNumberOfPlatform(arr,dep));
    }
int getMinimumNumberOfPlatform(Double []arrival,Double []dearture){

    ArrayList<Event> eventList=getEventList(arrival, dearture);
    int maxPlatformNo=1;
    int busyPlatform=0;
    for(Event eve:eventList){
        System.out.println(eve.getEventType()+"\t"+eve.getEventTime());
        if(eve.getEventType().equals("A")){
            busyPlatform++;
        }else if(eve.getEventType().equals("D")){
            busyPlatform--;
        }

        if(busyPlatform>maxPlatformNo){
            maxPlatformNo++;
        }
    }
    return maxPlatformNo;
}

ArrayList<Event> getEventList(Double []arrival,Double []dearture){
    ArrayList<Event> eventList=new ArrayList<Event>();
    for(int i=0;i<arrival.length;i++){
        Event ArrivalEve=new Event();
        ArrivalEve.setEventTime(arrival[i]);
        ArrivalEve.setEventType("A");
        Event Deartueeve=new Event();
        Deartueeve.setEventTime(dearture[i]);
        Deartueeve.setEventType("D");
        eventList.add(ArrivalEve);
        eventList.add(Deartueeve);
    }

    Collections.sort(eventList, (Event e1,Event e2)->{return (e1.getEventTime()-e2.getEventTime()>0?1:-1);});

    return eventList;
}
class Event{
  private Double eventTime;
  private String eventType;
public Double getEventTime() {
    return eventTime;
}
public void setEventTime(Double eventTime) {
    this.eventTime = eventTime;
}
public String getEventType() {
    return eventType;
}
public void setEventType(String eventType) {
    this.eventType = eventType;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Is this your answer to posted question which you want to share with others so they could use it in the future, or is this code your attempt but there is some problem with it. If it is second case then you should delete this "answer" and put this code directly in your question. Also describe problem you are having with it.

Comment: To update/clarify your question use `edit` option placed below it. To remove this answer use `delete` option placed below answer.